# POST request responds with 404 while GET request works fine .NET Core, React

Tags: c#, json, reactjs, api, asp.net-core

I am trying to make simple web application with one POST and one GET request, I was not able to find any solution and I am pretty desperate. I am using .NET Core with React, everything works fine, however I cannot get POST request to work, I always get 404 in console.

**MY POST Request from React class**

```
handleSubmit(event){
    superagent.post('api/WorkingTime/SaveWorkingTime')
    .send({
    Comment: this.state.Comment,
    Date: this.state.Date,
    Time: this.state.Time
    })
    .set('Accept', 'application/json')
    .then(function(res) {
    alert('Saved ' + JSON.stringify(res.body));
    });
}
```

**And this is my controller where I want to receive the JSON (Updated - trying to return TimeLog object, still 404)**

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class WorkingTimeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public IEnumerable<string> WorkingTime()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public TimeLog SaveWorkingTime([FromBody] TimeLog time)
    {
        return time;
    }
}
public class TimeLog
{
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
}
```

As I mentioned before, I get 200 OK when trying to fetch WorkingTime()

**THIS GET Request works fine**

```
   fetch('api/WorkingTime/WorkingTime')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        this.setState({ msg: data }); 
    });
```

**These are the payload data I need to send:**
[Screenshot from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGC1z.png)

Anyone please can tell me where the issue may be? Every help will be appreciated.

Comment: `SaveWorkingTime` should not return void.

Comment: The thing is that I tried to return TimeLog object, ActionResult, nothing seems to help, still cannot hit the breakpoint inside that method

Comment: I noticed you are returning void on post action. Have you tried to return something?

Comment: Either remove **SaveWorkingTime** from the url or add **[Route("SaveWorkingTime")]** to your action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("SaveWorkingTime")]
public IHttpActionResult SaveWorkingTime([FromBody] TimeLog time)
{
    // Perform saving
    return Ok(time);
}
```

added Route so i can acces that Post method. `api/WorkingTime/SaveWorkingTime` and it works. Tested with Postman.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing#routing-basics

Comment: Well, you answer helped to some extend, I am able to hit the breakpoint inside this method but my TimeLog object is null + I think you cannot return OK - you have to return TimeLog object otherwise you get an error.

Comment: You can return whatever you like. I've usualy return some `IHttpActionResult` because of status codes. Im not sure how that superagent works, but with axios i'ts just `axios.post(route,object)` and i can catch that object and parse it to TimeLog easy. Try to send some object that matches your TimeLog with postman, if that works then your post request is not valid.

Comment: Okay sorry, I tried to clean and rebuild solution and it helped. Thank you sir, your answer was changed while writing previous comment. Have a nice day

Comment: Thanks, you to :)